# Hyperlinks within AfxMessageBox

Tags: mfc

Is it possible to add hyperlinks to websites/email to messages that appear in windows created by `AfxMessageBox`? If not, what is a simple way to replace a `AfxMessageBox` call with one that spawns a similar-looking window with text that contain hyperlinks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the standard `MessageBox` for this (whether wrapped by `AfxMessageBox` or not) but there are a couple of other options for you:

1. If you're using Vista, you can use
   the [TaskDialog](http://blogs.chimpswithkeyboards.com/jonshute/archive/2006/11/26/230.aspx) class instead.
2. If not, you can adapt one of the
   MessageBox replacement classes (such
   as [XMessageBox](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/xmessagebox.aspx)) to support this
   functionality.

Comment: Thanks for two quick solutions. I ended up just using Qt, which provides hyperlinks in some of their rich-text dialogs.